# Results in listbox based on other listbox C# database

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox

i have different 2 different tabels in my database. 1 with all the clubs in the eredivisie and 1 with all the players.
table 1
idclubs, name , championships, established
table 2
idclubs, idplayer, nameplayer and some more information about him
Now i have 2 listboxes and in the first listbox i display all the clubs i have. but how do i make it so if i click a club in the first listbox the 2nd listbox shows the players from that club.
as far i have this code;

```
 public List<Spelers> Getspelers(string naam)
    {
        List<Spelers> Result = new List<Spelers>();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand selectSpelersCommand = new MySqlCommand("select naamspeler from spelers, clubs where clubs.idClubs = @idClubs and spelers.idClubs = @idClubs", connection);
            selectSpelersCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("naam", naam));
            using (var reader = selectSpelersCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Spelers speler = new Spelers();
                    speler.IdClubs = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    speler.IdSpelers = reader.GetInt32(1);
                    speler.NaamSpeler = reader.GetString(2);
                    speler.Doelpunten = reader.GetInt32(3);
                    speler.Gelekaarten = reader.GetInt32(4);
                    speler.Rodekaarten = reader.GetInt32(5);
                    Result.Add(speler);
                }
            }
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

and in my main code then:

```
 private void listboxClubs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager();
        List<Spelers> speler = db.Getspelers(listboxClubs.SelectedItem.ToString());
        listboxspelers.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Spelers spelers in speler)
        {
            listboxspelers.Items.Add(spelers);
        }
    }
```

Now if i click a club in the firstbox it sends the string. But how do i code it so the program looks up the idClubs from that club and then looks in the other table where he shows the players from that club then. If anybody could help me with this or link a other post i would reallly appreciate this.

Comment: is your mehod "public List<Spelers> Getspelers(int idClubs)" returing values?

Comment: at this moment it returns the string with the name of the club. but the problem is that i dont know how i make it so it returns the id of the club

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query is culprit

```
select Spelers.naam from clubs, spelers where clubs.idClubs = @idClubs and spelers.idClubs = @idClubs
```

notice

```
select Spelers.naam from
```

which says to sql give me just naam column of data, you should use * or list of columns names with "," separation

```
select Spelers.naam from clubs, spelers where clubs.idClubs = @idClubs and spelers.idClubs = @idClubs
```

Or

```
select Spelers.naam, spelers.idClubs from clubs, spelers where clubs.idClubs = @idClubs and spelers.idClubs = @idClubs
```

**Update:**

You should add a property in listbox instead of object

Add this

```
listboxspelers.Items.Add(spelers.NaamSpeler);
```

instead of

```
listboxspelers.Items.Add(spelers);
```

Comment: I edited my connection string and now it doesnt give any errors if i try to run it(see code in question). but if i select a club in the first listbox nothing happens and i cant see where it is going wrong with the debugger.

Comment: I changed this now and it still doesnt work. but if i use the debugger i cant see it go through the foreach loop. if i go throught the for each loper it says that in speler has a count of 0 what could be this the problem of?

Comment: can you try putting debugger inside "Getspelers" Method and see if it goes inside while and gets value?